# How to improve the UI of an existing Struts web application?

Tags: jsf, user-interface, struts, primefaces

There is an existing web application created in Struts. There is a need to totally redo the UI. What is the best way to improve the UI? Will intrducing JSF components like PrimeFaces into the existing Struts code be a good idea? Or what are the options available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to join Struts with JSF, since those are two different frameworks trying to do the same thing. So, in practice, you'll end-up rewriting your application. JSF pages and JSP (which are used by Struts) have different livecycle, JSF Beans are working in a different way then Struts Actions.

The point is to make use of that what you already have and make your JSP look better. I would choose good JavaScript UI library and rewrite JSP pages using it. ExtJS is a very good, if you want complete solution. If you want to create custom solution looke at jQuery, Backbone and Mustache templating engine.